# Statusbar colour appears inapropriate

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm applying this this to my base activity in manifest file.

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/darkRed</item>
</style>
```

[image]

But my status bar in base activity appears to be in blue colour. What am I suppose to do.

Comment: Check your _colorPrimary_

Answer (score 4):

This is because in style.xml file you have not use colorPrimaryDark to change status bar color.
So if you are using material design to create your application then please refer this guidelines as shown below:

https://material.google.com/

https://developer.android.com/training/material/index.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds"       tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/darkRed</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No there is no change, it again appears with the same colour.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7688.png

Comment: please take look at the attched image

Comment: Change the color code of your Color variables then.
Follow this.
https://www.materialpalette.com/indigo/deep-orange
Color variables can be found in two places, one in "color.xml" and one in "strings.xml". Remove the variable set from one.